# plugin not updated after update wordpress 3.5.2

Tags: upgrade

after upgrade to 3.5.2 plugin update not working showing error :

> Downloading update from
>   http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/adminimize.1.8.4.zip…
>
> Unpacking the update…
>
> Installing the latest version…
>
> The package could not be installed. The plugin contains no files.
>
> Plugin update failed.

and another problem is created I cant upload any image showing "HTTP ERROR" and cant see any thumbnail in media library.

any help appreciated...

Comment: Can you assure us that, your server configuration is Ok from the server-vendor?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a common bug in that version Adminimize. You might have better luck posting your question on WordPress.org under the plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/184-breaks-featured-image-functionality

Comment: Thanks David,I findout the problem.its not plugin or wp 3.5.2 problem. it is godaddy server problem.